# Catching exceptions by value, reference or pointer

Tags: c++, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [catch exception by pointer in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023032/catch-exception-by-pointer-in-c)

What is the best way to catch an exception: by value, reference or pointer and why?

Answer (score 2):

You nearly always want to catch exceptions by (usually const) reference.

Answer (score 2):

By `const` reference. You can avoid object copying.

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to raise any more exceptions so catching by reference is best

Answer (score 0):

By reference, unless you're doing Windows programming, where exceptions are typically caught by pointer.