# Throw by value and catch by reference in c++

Tags: c++, reference

Please I would like someone to explain to me the term and how to "throw by value and catch my reference". Someone said it to me, I am still a new programmer and I don't seem to understand yet.

Comment: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0321113586/items/sutter_item73.pdf

Answer (score 3):

"throw by value" means to not throw (raw) pointers.

When a pointer is thrown there is a good chance of double `delete` (which is UB) or no `delete` (leaking memory), because how can a handler know whether it's supposed to `delete` or not?

"catch by reference" means to catch by reference, preferably reference to `const`. 
That way you avoid slicing the exception object. For example, a handler can then simply use `dynamic_cast` to determine if a `std::exception` is really a `std::system_error`.

Answer (score 2):

Well catch by reference is

```
...}catch(myException &me){ }
```

So when you say `catch(myException me)` , it creates a new object, but in case of reference it does not. 
Additionally  exceptions  as references in catch blocks means polymorphic behavior is possible when accessing the object to handle the exception.

This is really helpful if the exception is off derived type. [Click Me For More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522299/c-catch-blocks-catch-exception-by-value-or-reference)

Comment: I take it "throw by value" means "there's no need to say `new`, i.e., `throw std::runtime_error("message")` instead of `throw new std::runtime_error("message")`