# CustomException headerfile

Tags: c++, exception, header-files

Obviously something goes wrong with my understanding of this topic, but I can't find out where. The thing I want to implement is a custom Exception called `CustomException`. What I have made does compile and can work, but I do think that I am making use of header files the wrong way. So I have made the following 3 files:

1. main.cpp

   ```
   #include "exception.h"

   int main() {
       try {
           throw CustomException();
       } catch (CustomException ce) {
           ce.doSomething();
       }
   }
   ```
2. exception.h

   ```
   #include <exception>

   class CustomException : public std::exception {
       private:
           char* msg;
       public:
           CustomException() {};
           void doSomething() {};
   };
   ```
3. exception.cpp

   ```
   #include "exception.h"

   CustomException::CustomException() {
   }

   void CustomException::doSomething() {
       printf("Hello World!");
   }
   ```

After I run this is the command line:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main.o
$ ./main.o
$
```

But the behaviour that I was looking for is, that "Hello World!" is printed to the command line. I am more used to JAVA, so maybe that is why I have a rough start with C++. Anyways I hope you can help me, because the tutorials I found differ from each other and don't make sense to me.

Comment: Any decent compiler will refuse this code - see the answer of user3553031

Comment: @DieterLücking Any standard-compliant compiler will take this code, because it has no idea the `exception.cpp` is even there :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're defining `CustomException::doSomething()` to do nothing: `{}`.  Leave out the `{}` method definitions in exception.h.  Then compile and link exception.cpp into your binary:

```
$ g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
$ g++ -c exception.cpp -o exception.o
$ g++ main.o exception.o -o main
$ ./main
```

Note that a ".o" suffix is normally used for object files, not for executables.

Comment: I have tried that too, but I get some errors like: `undefined reference to CustomException::CustomException()`

Comment: I had to do `#include <stdio>` too for the `printf`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what user3553031 said, there is another posslble problem with your code. In C++ you should catch exceptions by reference, not by value. Otherwise it can cause problems. See this: [C++ catch blocks - catch exception by value or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522299/c-catch-blocks-catch-exception-by-value-or-reference)

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, I have changed `CustomException ce` to `CustomException &ce` :)