# std::out_of_range exception when catching it?

Tags: c++

I'm getting this exception message in the IDE output log even though I have a code that catches it, if it happens.

[image]

Here's the code itself:

```
t_ptr obj_ptr;

try {
    obj_ptr = _objects.at(file);   
}
catch (std::out_of_range e) {
    return nullptr;
}

return obj_ptr.get();
```

Is it supposed to happen? It's not like I'm using `obj_ptr` when std::map.at() fails.

Comment: Don't catch exceptions by value. Use a const reference instead.

Comment: Why const? I've seen people that use just a reference, not a const one.

Comment: Usually you're not changing exceptions when you caught them, do you?

Comment: @Pilpel: Catching by `const` is basically pointless except as a good general habit; catching by reference is more important, though. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31638120/560648

Answer (score 3):

"First-chance" exception means just that the debugger noticed that an exception has been thrown. That's not an error (and in facts the execution goes on), just an aid to the programmer that may be on the look for exceptions being incorrectly swallowed.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this debugger message? I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I don't know, but why do you care?

Comment: When I compile and run my application, it looks buggy if these messages pop up all the time.

Comment: @Pilpel: Yes, you probably can. What prevented you from simply looking through the menu options?