# With Iibjson try, catch is not working, in target Cross compiled linux board

Tags: c++, linux, libjson

I have a try catch inside a contructor in C++ class

```
class jsonAdap
{
  jsonAdap(const char *text)
 {
   try
   {
   parsejson(text);//this calls a libjson function that throws the expection throw std::invalid_argument("exception")
   }
   catch(std::invalid_argument)
   {
     cout<<"Exception captured:"<<endl"
    }

 }
}
```

When i'm creating an object of this class, it gives the error and stops terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'.

this is the case with cross compiled on ARM (with -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -pthread -Wno-reorder -std=gnu++0x -fstack-protector-all -Wno-format-contains-nul -Wno-format-extra-args -Wno-format-zero-length) ,

but on windows it catches the error properly.

When i try a sample application with the same options from cross compiling, on the board it works perfectly.

Is there any compiler setting that could be contributing to this behaviour, that i may not have noticed?

Any suggestions?

below is the sample application

```
class ctest
{
public:
ctest()
{

    int x = -1;
   try {
      cout << "Inside try \n";
      if (x < 0)
      {
        throw std::invalid_argument("test");
         cout << "After throw (Never executed) \n";
      }
   }
   catch (std::invalid_argument &e)  {
      cout << "Exception Caught \n";
   }
}


void test(){};
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  cout << "Before try \n";
  ctest c;
  cout << "cdone "<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug with another chained `catch(...)`

Comment: Won't solve your problem - but you should catch exceptions by reference! See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522299/c-catch-blocks-catch-exception-by-value-or-reference

Comment: You might want to post the sample application, too, so we can see what you did differently there...

Comment: tried chained catch(...)  no avil

Comment: caught exception as reference catch (std::invalid_argument &e) , still had no avail

Comment: @buddingspacer I knew before - just wanted to give a hint for good practice (else I would have written an answer instead...).

Comment: Difference: you're generating the exception yourself... Have you verified that libjson has been compiled with exceptions enabled? This is not always the case in libraries compiled for embedded systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem seems to be in libjson:JSONStream, which has the overloaded << & parse function that indeed throws a exception, but in their signature they have just throw(), indicating that it doesnot throws an exception.

hence when exception happens actually , the terminate is called as explained here
http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

The solution is to change the signature of the libjson JSONStream class functions ( << & parse) - to raise a bug ticket in libjson to modify the signature of the JSONStream class functions ( << & parse)

And it works finally.

The Windows compiler seems to ignore this, but not the linux g++ compiler