# Is throw by value and catch by reference the law of thumb?

Tags: c++

I am so confused and fed up with C++: As I have been taught "passing by reference or pointer" overcomes getting copies of parameters passed in a function.

So in an exception-handling scenario according to the law of thumb: throw by value, catch by reference.

Why Stroustrup in his "A Tour of C++" catches by value? eg:

```
void test()
{
    try {
        std::vector v(−27);
    }
    catch (std::length_error) {
        // handle negative size
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc) {
        // handle memory exhaustion
    }
}
```

This example is copied from the book. Page 59. (Invariants).

Comment: In what way is that "inconsistent"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I am really fed up. I probably didn't use the precise term.

Comment: How is allowing something *new* being inconsistent? What code is going to break as a result? And Bjarne may make mistakes or have another point to make. We program machines, we aren't machines ourselves.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Do you mean a mistake in the book?

Comment: Yes. The concept of an [errata](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour_printing2.html) exists because authors may make mistakes. Besides, in this case, he only cares about the exception type, not the exception object itself. It's not the end of the world to catch by value. It's not overly *good*, but it's hardly something to get "fed up" with.

Comment: The purpose of changing the language is to make the language better (for some subjective definition of better). Not everyone agrees that all the changes succeed in doing that, but that is the goal nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you all guys. I do really appreciate your useful help especially when I get stuck and lost.

Comment: Note that `std::bad_alloc` has no data members and thus is extremely cheap to copy. And that it hardly ever is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why Stroustrup in his "A Tour of C++" catches by value?

Unless you want to copy the exception for some reason *(e.g. store a custom exception type)*, you should always catch by `const&`. This might have been an oversight from Bjarne, or in that particular snippet it didn't really matter whether or not the exception was copied.

Related:

- ["Always catch exceptions by reference"](https://blog.knatten.org/2010/04/02/always-catch-exceptions-by-reference/)
- [C++ catch blocks - catch exception by value or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522299/c-catch-blocks-catch-exception-by-value-or-reference)

---

> Why C++ is changing inconsistently? I mean from time to time everything changes. eg: in C++ 11:

There is no inconsistency here - `static_assert` merely became more flexible, as it doesn't force the user to provide an error message anymore. This is useful for cases where the boolean condition itself is self-explanatory and an error message would not add anything useful.

Comment: How can a beginner like me to spot those "Errata" of the Designer of the language?

Comment: @WonFeiHong: posting on StackOverflow is a good start. C++ is a very big and complicated language, and everyone makes mistakes... In this case, the mistake/oversight is not really problematic - just keep in mind that catching by `const&` should always be the first choice unless you really want to copy an exception for some reason.

Comment: @WonFeiHong, there is no single designer. Subscribe to standardization comittee mailing. IIRC LWG issues get posted there.

Comment: Thank you too much! Yes indeed in my examples I catch by `const&`. Thanks for making it so clear. Also here on S.O I really get a very useful help.

Comment: @Incomputable: Thank you.