# Beginner how to handle exception caused by user input being of incorrect type

Tags: c++, exception

This post may be a bit different from the usual questions about exceptions in c++.

In C++, how does someone go about handling user input errors, by this specifically I mean when a user is being prompted for an integer and they enter a float or a string/char or vice versa. You know like someone entering their name when being prompted for their age.

I'm basically talking about what in C++ is equivalent to what would be in Python something like:

```
try:
[code to prompting user for an integer.]
exception ValueError:
[code to run if exception is thrown.]
```

If one of you awesome guys has the spare time to explain this to me in a way a beginner would be able to understand it would be **hugely** appreciated guys.

Thanks.

Comment: the question is quite okay but could have been more precise and a lil less clumsy. Try asking the exact point if you can. avoid large amounts of detailing. *try Avoiding unnecessary things apart from question* (Last 3 para of your question and maybe the 1st para too)

Comment: What do you want to do if an input error occurs? It might be easier to just keep looping until you get what you want rather than using exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

The basic example for try catch is something like this:

```
try
{
    // code that throws an exception
}
catch(...)
{
    // exception handling
}
```

Note that the three dots are perfectly valid for catching all exceptions, though you do not know "what" you catch. This is why you should prefer specifying the type in the parentheses.

The exception to be caught can be any type beginning from int and ending with a pointer to an object that derives from a exception class. This concept is very flexible, however you must know what exception may occur.

This may be a more concrete example, using std::excpetion: Note the catch by reference.

```
try
{
    throw std::exception();
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Next example assumes you write C++ with MFC libraries. It clarifies that CException catch is executed because CFileException derives from CException. The CException object deletes itself if it is not needed anymore. Unless your exception derives from CException you should not throw a pointer and stick to the example above.

```
try
{
    throw new CFileException();
}
catch (CException* e)
{
    // CFileException is caught
}
```

Last but not least this is also important: You may define several catch blocks to catch different exceptions:

```
try
{
    throw new CFileException();
}
catch (CMemoryException* e)
{
    // ignore e
}
catch (CFileException* e)
{
    // rethrow exception so it gets handeled else where
    throw;
}
catch (CException* e)
{
    // note that catching the base class should be the last catch
}
```

Comment: You should always, throw by value and catch by reference.

Comment: to be more precise catch by `const` reference(usually).

Comment: you are right, I updated my post calrifying that this should be done for MFC CException objects only.

Comment: Every time I discover something new about MFC (which I never used), it's facepalming. Seriously, how can it be so *wrong* ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I do not want to make any excuses but provide information: If this is correct http://stackoverflow.com/a/2023134/426662 MFC supported sort of try/catch before it was standardized. Somewhere in 1994/95 with MFC 3.0 they changed it to use C++ try catch but also wanted compatability with their old method which apparantely used heap allocated objects. Would be nice if they had dropped it, lots of programmers may think differently because they do not need to update their code.

Comment: According to [MSDN Exceptions: Catching and Deleting Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e5twxsh.aspx) after catching an MFC exception which is being handled and not re-thrown, you must delete the exception using the `Delete()` method as in if you have `catch (CException *e) {` then before the closing brace you need `e->Delete();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple if..else loop for simple user input validations. You can use exceptions in pretty similar way

e.g.

```
try {
      ...code that can generate the error...
   } catch (some_exception& e) {
     ...code that handles the error...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are handled in C++ using a try-catch block. Exception handling is one improved feature of C++ over C. Exception handling prevents programs from crashing with unknown errors.

```
 try
    {
         //code to be tried
    }
    catch(Exception& e)
    {
          //make user understand the problem
      throw [expression]
    }
```

you can read through the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dekhbbc.aspx)
Or for a basic understanding you can read [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/exceptions.html)

Comment: *Exception handling prevents programs from crashing with unknown errors* & hiding such scenarios through exception handling rather than solving them is a very bad practice.

Comment: @Als:exceptions caught are to be thrown too. is that worth special mentioning? ;-)

Comment: *exceptions caught are to be thrown too* Pray tell Why? Are you on a `throw`ing frenzy? If you can handle an exception Once you `catch`it why do you want to `throw` it again?

Comment: oh no. was in a little hurry. When an exceptional circumstance arises within try block, an exception is thrown that transfers the control to the exception handler. is that alright

Comment: *When an exceptional circumstance arises* resulting in call to `throw someThing;`, An exceptional situation without a `throw` called does nothing really.

Comment: i agree. its almost like leaving it unhandled. Hope we are not confusing the original poster of the question.

Comment: Catch by reference, catch by reference, catch by reference... please.

Answer (score 0):

You can yourself inherit from base Exception class to have your own Exception type or use prepared Exception class like those my friends has bring them up there.
About your case you should probably need to provide an Exception based on base exception class to
evaluate input first and throw the exception you write exception if did not satisfy condition your want.
like this:

```
class myException:Exception {
...
}

int evaluateInput(input) {
 if
 ...
 else
  throw myException;
}

// Get input from user

try:
 cin>>input;
 evaluateInput(input);
catch(myException)
 doWhatYouWant;
```