# Identify constant value in llvm

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm writing a condition to see if a const llvm::Value* is a constant. The code is as following:

```
if(const Constant* c = dynamic_cast<Constant>(val)){
    ......
}
```

"val" here is a const llvm::Value*, however, the compiler says

```
error: 'llvm::Constant' is not a reference or pointer
if(const Constant* c = dynamic_cast<Constant>(val)){
                       ^           ~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I modify it?

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129728)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use the constant inside of the if block then you can use isa<>()

```
if(isa<Constant>(val)){ ...... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type used in `dynamic_cast` must be a pointer or reference type. I'm guessing you'd want to keep the `const`ness as well.

Try this:

```
dynamic_cast<const Constant*>(val)
//           ^^^^^         ^
```

Comment: Still not work, but dyn_cast<Constant>(val) can compile, I haven't check the correctness of it.

Comment: apologies, I didn't realize you were needing the llvm `dyn_cast` function [docs](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates)

Comment: looks like directly swapping to `dyn_cast<Constant>(val)` is exactly what you want