# Surprising behavior of catch of a pointer by reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, try-catch, c++17

It is bad practive to throw non-exception objects. That being said, when I run the following code, I would have expected to see the "got it ! " messsage, but do not.

```
const char* hello = "hello";
try {
  throw hello;
}
catch (const char*& e) {
  std::cout << "got it ! " << std::endl;
}
catch (...) {
  std::cout << "got something..." << std::endl;
}
```

Removing `&` will fix the example, but what is going on here ?

**Is this a bug in MSVC ?**

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/629db27eb8144640 - both GCC and Clang pring "got it"

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I believe OP might be using VC++ https://rextester.com/live/AMEQ10445

Comment: You should check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023032/catch-exception-by-pointer-in-c

Comment: If you throw directly `"hello"` instead of the variable, it will fix the example for VC++.

Comment: Are you saying its a bug then ?