# Need I Destroy a Thrown Object Manually?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

I just wonder if in C++, need I destroy a thrown object manually?

In the following code, how to destroy the thrown 0?

```
try
{
   ...
   throw 0;
}
catch(int i)
{
   // How to destroy the thrown 0?
}
```

In the following code, how to destroy the thrown CString object?

```
try
{
   ...
   throw CString(_T("Hello"));
}
catch(CString& str)
{
   // How to destroy the thrown str?
}
```

In the following code, I can destroy the thrown object since it is allocated from heap as a CString*

```
try
{
   ...
   throw new CString(_T("Hello"));
}
catch(CString* lpStr)
{
   delete lpStr;
}
```

Comment: In the first two examples, you *don't* "destroy" the objects. That will happen automatically as part of the exception handling.

Comment: More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023032/catch-exception-by-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to and are not allowed to manually destroy the exception object or the `catch` parameter.

`throw` will copy-initialize a new unnamed object, the *exception object*, from its operand and this object is then caught by the `catch` block. *Caught* here means that the parameter of the `catch` block will be initialized from the exception object.

When the `catch` block exits its parameter is automatically destroyed and if it exits without re-throwing (and if there are no `std::exception_ptr` referencing it left), the exception object will also be destroyed, the same way that objects with automatic storage duration are destroyed when the block in which they are declared exits or that temporary objects are destroyed when the full-expression they were created in ends.

In your first code example the exception object of type `int` is initialized with the value `0` and you capture it by-value, meaning that you are creating a new object of type `int` as the variable in the `catch` parameter, initialized from the exception object. When the `catch` block exits the `int` from the `catch` parameter is destroyed and, assuming you didn't re-throw, the exception object is also destroyed.

In your second example the exception object of type `CString` is initialized from the temporary object created by `CString(_T("Hello"))`. The temporary `CString(_T("Hello"))` is destroyed after the exception object is initialized, as that is the end of the full-expression in which it was created.

Due to copy elision the temporary will however never be really materialized and the `CString` exception object is directly initialized from `_T("Hello")`. (This is mandatory since C++17 and was allowed before.)

You catch the exception object by reference, meaning that no new copy will be created and `str` will refer to the exception object.
When leaving the `catch` block without re-throwing, the exception object will again be destroyed automatically.

In the third example you are throwing a `CString*` and you capture it by value, so the same considerations as in example 1 apply. When leaving the `catch` block without re-throwing, the pointer `lpStr` and the exception object, which is also a `CString*`, will be destroyed.

Destroying a pointer does however not mean that the object the pointer is pointing to is destroyed. (This is why raw pointers should not be used as owning pointers.)

Therefore, since the pointer points to an object created with `new`, you indeed need to destroy that object by a call to `delete lpStr;` if you don't want the `new`ed `CString` to leak. This `delete` however *does not delete the exception object or the `catch` parameter*. `delete` destroys the object that the pointer given to it points to. The `catch` parameter  is the pointer `lpStr` itself, an automatic storage duration variable that cannot be `delete`d. The exception object is another pointer (with the same value) and is unnamed without any possible way to reference it in your example.

You should prefer catching by-reference as in your second example and you should avoid using `new` for anything really. There are smart pointers `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` for free store allocations that with correct ownership semantics.

Comment: Hi, @walnut, Thank you for your answer. Just wonder for example 1, should I catch int& instead of int, like this? catch(int& i)

Comment: @alancc For fundamental types it doesn't really matter whether you catch by-reference or by-value. But if you want to be consistent, then you can catch always (including `int`) by-reference (e.g. `catch(int& i)`), yes.