# Why doesn't std::exception have a move constructor?

Tags: c++, exception, move-semantics

The best practice regarding exceptions in C++ seems to be [throw by value, catch by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023032/catch-exception-by-pointer-in-c). I had a look at `<exception>` and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) and I see that `std::exception` has a copy-constructor but no move-constructor, why is this? Wouldn't having a move-constructor allow cheaply catching by value and thus simplifying the guidelines?

Comment: Since catching by value would cause slicing, and make exception type hierarchies pointless, I don't see the guidelines changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The descendants of `std::exception` do own data. For example `std::runtime_error` owns its `what()` message.  And that message is dynamically allocated because it can be an arbitrarily long message.

However, the copy constructor is marked `noexcept` (implicitly) because the `std::exception` copy constructor is `noexcept`.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

int
main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<std::runtime_error>{});
}
```

The *only* way for a class to own a dynamically allocated message, and have a `noexcept` copy constructor, is for that ownership to be shared (reference counted).  So `std::runtime_error` is essentially a const, reference counted string.

There was simply no motivation to give these types a move constructor because the copy constructor is not only already very fast, but the exceptional path of program is only executed in exceptional circumstances.  About the only thing a move constructor for `std::runtime_error` could do is eliminate an atomic increment/decrement.  And no one cared.

> Wouldn't having a move-constructor allow cheaply catching by value and thus simplifying the guidelines?

You can already cheaply catch by value.  But the guideline exists because exceptions are often part of an inheritance hierarchy, and catching by value would slice the exception:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int
main()
{
    try
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("my message");
    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output (for me):

```
std::exception
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked on a couple of compilers and apparently the `try/catch` mechanism doesn't use move semantics.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct err {
    err() { cout << "created err" << endl; }
    err(const err&) { cout << "copied err" << endl; } // Compilation error if this is commented out
    err(err&&) noexcept { cout << "moved err" << endl; }
    ~err() { cout << "destroyed err" << endl; }
};

void foo() {
    throw err{};
}

int main() {
    try {
        cout << "calling foo" << endl;
        foo();
        cout << "called foo" << endl;
    }
    catch (err e) {
        cout << "caught err" << endl;
    }
}
```

*Output:*

> calling foo
> created err
> copied err
> caught err
> destroyed err
> destroyed err

So having a move constructor would be meaningless.

Why this is so is probably a matter for another question :)